# Sed, match words (identifiers) in a list of identifiers except the last

Tags: sed, command-line

Given a list of identifiers in the following format:

```
test_one another_one lol heres1 wow_the_last
```

I'm trying to use sed to replace it with any of the following:

```
test_one,another_one,lol,heres1
test_one, another_one, lol, heres1
{test_one, another_one, lol, heres1}
{test_one,another_one,lol,heres1}
```

I was able to do this with the following sed command:

```
sed -e 's/\(\w*\)\s/\1,/g'
```

but I was hoping to find a more robust solution that doesn't depend on the last word in the list  not having a trailing space. Instead, I was trying to get the match to be based on not being at the end of the line or having another word following. But my attempts in this direction either didn't match anything or matched too much.

```
sed -e 's/\(\w*\)^$/\1,/g'
sed -e 's/\(\w*\)[^$]/\1,/g'
```

I tried the above but the first one doesn't seem to match anything, and the one below it produces the following:

```
test_one,another_one,lol,heres,
```

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`? Because `perl -anle 'pop @F; print join ", ", @F'`.

Comment: @melpomene i have perl available, but this actually doesn't work. it excludes the final word. I'm looking to output all words in the list with commas added in between all but the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood you correctly but using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$1=$1;NF--;print}' file
test_one,another_one,lol,heres1
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { OFS="," }  # set the output field separator to a comma
{
    $1=$1          # rebuild the record, ie. use the commas
    NF--           # reduce field count by one
    print          # output
}' file
```